# Fetching Access Token in Distributed environment

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

I have an external api which i need to access using tokens. My service build using spring boot uses service user credentials to retrieve token and access it. These tokens are valid for particular duration. If i want to deploy multiple version of the same service for HA/scalability its causing issues when token expires or during the startup when the servers starts up in the same time. I can build a custom solution for fixing this, but i am looking for best practices and existing libraries for handling this kind of scenario. /approaches.

Answer (score 0):

for distributed authorization servers : use JDBCTokenStore

In your specific case make your service app as Resource server by using 

`@EnableResourceServer`

and in your application.yml file specify these properties 

`security:
  oauth2:
    resource:
      token-info-uri: http://localhost:9191/oauth/check_token 
    client:
      client-id: yourclientId
      client-secret: yourClientSecret`